# Mini pc won't turn on with power button, but WILL turn on using the power button if you unplug power and plug it back in

Tags: boot, debian, uefi, power

I have a small mini-pc from Aliexpres with a celeron n5105 in it, 16gb RAM and 500gb ssd (both Crucial brand).
It is running Proxmox (Debian) and it was working fine.
After some fiddling around with the SSD using gparted I messed something up, so I decided to just reinstall proxmox the regular way.

[image]

After that I noticed that the power button does NOT work anymore. However if I unplug the power, plug it back in again, and then press the power button, it works 100% of the time, until I shut it down again and need to repeat the process.

I have also tried to press the power button when it's running. This successfully shuts down the pc, so the power button is properly connected (and part of the motherboard). See images below.

I have also reset the BIOS to it's default settings without success.

Lastly I checked if the "/sys/firmware/efi" directory was there, it was not. This makes me think it is a problem with the bootloader. However I have no clue how to fix this. I would prefer not to reinstall proxmox again since it is already up and running.
Does anyone have some idea on what the problem might be? Help is greatly appreciated!

notes:

- Holding the power button does nothing, no blinks (EDIT: It does now)
- using a bootable USB running Ventoy as primary boot option, it still won't work (No idea if Ventoy is uefi though, but this information might be useful)
- It happened after I messed up in GParted.
- After the GParted messup I just reinstalled Proxmox the regular way and did not touch GParted again.
- Pulling out the SSD, restoring BIOS to default and booting once in Alpine linux installer, I can verify there is a "/sys/firmware/efi" directory confirming it booted using uefi. After a shutdown the power button still did not work.
- Clicking on "UEFI Firmware Settings" in GNU GRUB when booting from the proxmox drive, will result in a shutdown without the button working
- Regular reboot DOES work
- I ran a proxmox recovery thingy included in the installer iso. Now the sys/firmware/efi folder can be located. And when off, holding the button for an extended period (10s) will successfully boot the system. Regularly pressing it does not work yet.
  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a AliExpress N5105 router box with 4 x Intel 226v NICs as well.  Same issue with Windows 11 Pro.  It seems Windows doesnt handle the C-State setup in the BIOS very well.  I just disabled the C-State completely.  This resolved it.

Press DEL -> Bios
Go to Advanced -> Power & Performance
Go to CPU - Power Mgmt Control
Scroll down to C States -> change to disabled

Then I like for my device to stay on after a power loss, so go back to Advanced -> hardware monitor -> change power recovery to "stay on".

Maybe Windows has an update for this or firmware update to fix this issue.  I will be installing OpenBSD on this so doesnt matter for me.

Comment: I am running Proxmox on mine. I still have this issue, but since it is running 24/7, I don't care much about the need to hold the power button. However, I will check this week if your trick works for proxmox. I'll report back later!

Comment: Sounds good.  I had no issues with Ubuntu 23.04 (latest) and OpenBSD 7.3 under the default BIOS settings with C States enabled.  I looked for firmware updates in Windows and in Ubuntu, there were none.

Comment: so as an update....OpenBSD doesnt handle the c states well either.  the ACPI process had the first cpu core pegged high with acpi0 interrupts.  No adjustments I tried worked.  I installed FreeBSD and its legit.  No issues so far.  This is probably due to the fact that PFsense backports all their drivers for these small router devices into FreeBSD upstream.

Answer (score 1):

I’m having the same issue. But often I find that unplugging and plugging in again only works after 10 to 15 attempts. There seems to be no logic to it. I tried disabling C states but it makes no difference. Any ideas? I’m using Proxmox but don’t see why the OS makes any difference as this is an issue before the PC even boots.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).